# Calculating the Integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j(w_0-w)t} dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

I have encountered the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j(w_0-w)t} dt$$

where $w_0$ and $w$ are constants. I know that the result of this integral is $2\pi\delta(w-w_0)$, where $\delta$ represents the Dirac delta function. However, I'm not entirely sure why this is the case.

What I know:

- The integral I want to calculate is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j(w_0-w)t} dt$.
- The result is $2\pi\delta(w-w_0)$.

What I don't understand:

- I'm looking for an explanation or a step-by-step solution to understand why this integral evaluates to $2\pi\delta(w-w_0)$.

I have searched for explanations and proofs, but I couldn't find a clear and detailed one. Any insights, explanations, or references to resources that can help me understand the reasoning behind this result would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418615/question-regarding-a-non-rigourous-proof-that-the-fourier-transform-of-1-is-th?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792063/fourier-transform-dirac-delta, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242796/fourier-transform-of-dirac-delta-function, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500877/the-inverse-fourier-transform-of-1-is-diracs-delta, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335309/dirac-delta-function-inverse-fourier-transform.

Comment: @Ted Zhu, Dirac delta functions are tricky things--they're not really "functions".  They can be represented in different ways (one of them being what you present above), and what classifies something as a Dirac delta function is how it is used under an integral sign (often with other functions).  So in order to prove that the above is a Dirac delta function, you need to show that it obeys the properties expected of one.  Is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: They cannot downvote yet?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=e^{-j\omega_0 t}$.  Note that $f\notin L^1$ and so the object written $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{j(\omega-\omega_0)}\,dt$ is not defined as either a Lebesgue integral or an improper Riemann integral .

However, the Fourier Transform of $f$ can be defined in terms of Tempered [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).  Tempered Distributions are linear continuous mappings from the [Schwartz Space $\mathbb{S}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) to the complex numbers.  The Dirac Delta is a Tempered Distribution.

---

Let $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$ (i.e., $\phi$ is a Schwartz Function).  Then, the Fourier Transform of $f$ is given distributionally by

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi\rangle&=\langle f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega_0 t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)e^{j\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt\\\\
&=2\pi \phi(\omega_0)
\end{align}$$

where the last equality is a consequence of the Fourier Inversion Theorem (See Appendix).  Therefore, in distribution we have

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)=2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$$

---

**APPENDIX:  PROOF OF THE INVERSION THEOREM FOR SCHWARTZ FUNCTIONS**

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814073/fourier-representation-of-diracs-delta-function/3818103#3818103), [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038581/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-sinnx-pi-x-is-a-delta-function/4038638#4038638) and in the Alternative Development section of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152426/definite-integral-for-exp-i-ax/4152554#4152554), I proved that $\frac{\sin(Lt)}{\pi t}$ is a nascent Dirac Delta.  Using this result, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega_0 t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)e^{j\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega+\omega_0)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega+\omega_0) \int_{-L}^L e^{j\omega t}\,dt\,d\omega\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty} 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega+\omega_0) \frac{\sin(L\omega)}{\pi \omega}\,d\omega\\\\
&= 2\pi\phi(\omega_0)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: And feel free to upvote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.